# How to refresh fragment with recycle view when we delete some image file from recycle view in Android java

Tags: java, android

fragment_picture.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/picture_fragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F1F1F1">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:spanCount="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_picture" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/group_no_data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="imv_no_data,tv_no_data" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imv_no_data"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_no_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_no_data"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:text="@string/no_image"
        android:textColor="@color/color_828282"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_no_data" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

FragmentPicture.java

```
public class PictureFragment extends BaseFragment<FragmentPictureBinding> {

    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_DELETE = 376;
    private PictureAdapter pictureAdapter;
    private int pos;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh;

    @Override
    protected void initView() {
        pictureAdapter = new PictureAdapter(new ArrayList<>(), getContext());
        pictureAdapter.setCallBackAdapter(item -> openMedia(item.getPath()));

        pictureAdapter.setCallBackPicture(new PictureAdapter.CallBackPicture() {
            @Override
            public void onClickMore(String s, int adapterPosition, View v) {
                showPopupMenuMore(s, adapterPosition, v);
            }
        });


        binding.rcvPicture.setAdapter(pictureAdapter);
        binding.swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getData();
                }else {
                    if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity){

                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).askPermissionStorageMain();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                getData();
            }
            binding.swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
        });
        binding.swipeRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.color_accent,
                android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getData();
            }
        } else {
            getData();
        }
    }

    public void onCLickMore(String item, int pos, View view) {
        showPopupMenuMore(item, pos, view);
    }

    private void showPopupMenuMore(String item, int pos, View view) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getContext(), view);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_more_picture);
        popupMenu.show();
//        popupMenu.getMenu().getItem(1).setEnabled(PreferencesHelper.getBoolean(PreferencesHelper.KEY_SAVE_AS_GIF, true));
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(menuItem ->{
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.share_picture:
                    shareMedia(item);
                    break;
                case R.id.delete_picture:
                    this.pos = pos;
                    deletePhoto(item);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    private void getData() {
        getAllFilesInPicture()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap(this::mapFiles)
                .subscribe(datas -> {
                    if (datas.isEmpty()) {
                        binding.rcvPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        binding.groupNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        binding.rcvPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        binding.groupNoData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        pictureAdapter.addDatas(datas);
                    }
                },throwable -> {
                });
    }

    public Single<File[]> getAllFilesInPicture() {
        return Single.create(sub -> {
            File[] listFile = Storage.getFilesImageInStorage(requireContext());

            if (listFile != null) {
                sub.onSuccess(listFile);
            } else {
                sub.onSuccess(new File[]{});
            }
        });
    }

    public Single<List<VideoFile>> mapFiles(@NonNull File[] listFile) {
        return Single.create(sub -> {
            long previousDate = 0;
            List<VideoFile> videoFiles = new ArrayList<>();

            Arrays.sort(listFile, (f1, f2) -> Long.compare(f1.lastModified(), f2.lastModified()));
            List<String> pictureFile = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = listFile.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                VideoFile videoFile = new VideoFile();
                if (!Toolbox.isSameDay(previousDate, listFile[i].lastModified())) {
                    VideoFile header = new VideoFile();
                    header.setHeader(true);
                    header.setLastModified(listFile[i].lastModified());
                    videoFiles.add(header);
                }
                videoFile.setPath(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                videoFile.setName(listFile[i].getName());
                videoFile.setSize(listFile[i].length());
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(listFile[i].getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), options);
                int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
                int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
                videoFile.setResolution(imageWidth+"x"+imageHeight);
                videoFile.setSize(listFile[i].length());
                videoFile.setLastModified(listFile[i].lastModified());
                videoFiles.add(videoFile);
                previousDate = listFile[i].lastModified();

                pictureFile.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

            }
            sub.onSuccess(videoFiles);
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void initControl() {

    }

    private void itemToItem(String filepath){

    }

    private void openMedia(String filePath) {

        Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                getContext(), getContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                new File(filePath));
        try {
            Intent openVideoIntent = new Intent();
            openVideoIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    .setDataAndType(
                            fileUri,
                            getContext().getContentResolver().getType(fileUri));
            getContext().startActivity(openVideoIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void shareMedia(String filePath) {
        Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                getContext(), getContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                new File(filePath));
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent()
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri)
                .setType(filePath.endsWith(".mp4") ? "video/mp4" : "image/*");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
    }

    protected void deletePhoto(String path) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alert.setTitle("Delete");
        alert.setMessage("Do you want to delete this image ?");

        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //This will delete my Image from recycleView
                deleteMedia(path);
                //I Wan't to add here code for refreshing recycle view

            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alert.show();

    }

    private void deleteMedia(String filePath) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            new File(filePath).delete();
            //removeItem(pos);
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{filePath}, new String[]{"video/mp4"},
                    (path1, uri) -> {

                    });
        } else {
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{filePath}, new String[]{"video/mp4"},
                    (path1, uri) -> {
                        if (uri != null) {
                            try {
                                if (getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null) != -1) {
                                
                                    //removeItem(pos);
                                }
                                swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                                List<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
                                uris.add(uri);
                                requestDeletePermission(uris);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    }

    private void requestDeletePermission(List<Uri> uriList) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            try {
                PendingIntent pi = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uriList);
                startIntentSenderForResult(pi.getIntentSender(), REQUEST_PERMISSION_DELETE, null, 0, 0,
                        0, null);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void removeItem(int pos) {
        getBaseActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
            pictureAdapter.getList().remove(pos);
            pictureAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);
            if (pictureAdapter.getList().get(pictureAdapter.getList().size() - 1).isHeader()) {
                pictureAdapter.getList().remove(pictureAdapter.getList().size() - 1);
                pictureAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(pictureAdapter.getList().size() - 1);
            }
            if (pictureAdapter.getList().isEmpty()) {
                binding.rcvPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                binding.groupNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                binding.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                binding.rcvPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                binding.groupNoData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            //Have?
        });
    }



    @Override
    protected boolean isNeedRefresh() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected FragmentPictureBinding getViewBinding(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        return FragmentPictureBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedEvent(RxBusType type, Object data) {
        switch (type) {
            case SCREEN_SHOT:
            case NOTI_MEDIA_CHANGE:
                getData();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I added popup menu on picture_item of recycle view and when we press delete button of popup menu I send String path of that image to deletePhoto(item); and that method delete image.

after delete image we have to manually refresh fragment by pull refresh But can add any automatic method for refreshing fragment In this case?

Please see deletePhoto method where I deleted photo but when
I tried refresh with removepos method its crash

I tried also many methods from stackoverflow but did not worked on my case
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have already done everything uncomment your removeItem method and add `pictureAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end of removeItem method

This will reload the data set of your adapter

If you know the position of the deleted element you can use

```
pictureAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
```

This will tell your adapter you remove an item from the data set on a specific position

Comment: I tried this but This method crash my app

Comment: Can you post the logcat error ?

Comment: http://doc.growmoon.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/logcat.txt

Comment: This is the crash IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
I don't know what are you doing in  pictureAdapter.addDatas(datas);
But I'm pretty sure you do something wrong here 
The error appears because you remove an item from your list and you try to refresh.
Check your getItemCount method inside your adapter and look if you have the correct size

Comment: Ok I got issue, thank for helping me